# is it required to put this class in the manifest file? class not extending anything. Android

Tags: android, manifest

If the class TestClass is not extending any other class like Activity.  It would be a helper class.  In this case is it required to register this class in the manifest file?   Or because this class is not displaying a UI or extending any UI class, can I leave it out of the manifest without causing problems?

```
 <activity android:name=".TestClass"> 
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.example.TESTCLASS"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to register a helper or utility class in your manifest.

Only the components listed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html), namely Activities, Services, Providers and Receivers need to be registered.

Other classes like helper classes or classes extending SQLiteOpenHelper etc. need not be included in the manifest.